# Plupload jquery library not working in IE10

Tags: jquery, plupload

I have a ui dialog where user's can upload their images. But I have problem with IE10. It's  not bringing file upload folder in IE 10. I am using Plupload jquery files with latest version. It works very well with Firefox, Opera, Chrome and IE9 but not IE10.

Clicking on 'Add Files' button does nothing.

Can someone please help me in right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the issue and found through plupload Git commit, through below link

[plupload Git commit](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/758#issuecomment-15955564)

I have found that the variable **w.features.triggerDialog** was false in file **plupload.full.js**. So it needs to change

```
triggerDialog: (j.ua.gecko && h.FormData || j.ua.webkit || j.ua.windows)
```

from

```
triggerDialog: (j.ua.gecko && h.FormData || j.ua.webkit)
```

Now it's working fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks changing the bottom line to of code to the top one you wrote worked!